# Handling duplicate filenames in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, duplicates, filenames

I'm writing an iOS project in Xcode 4 that uses several third-party libraries. One of those libraries contains a file with the same name as a file in my project. I'd like to put both files in separate groups, but it seems like Xcode only allows one instance of each filename in the entire project.

Is there a way around this other than renaming one of the files?

**Edit:** The files are Objective-C source files (`.h` and `.m`). I'm not familiar with mapping groups to folders. How do I tell Xcode to make my groups separate folders on disk?

Comment: What type of file is it?

Comment: Are the groups mapped to different folders? If both groups are using the same folder, then you'll of course run into problems when adding the second file of the same name.

Comment: Are you sure it wont work if it's in another directory? If yes, then I'd advise you to just rename the library files with the name of the library appended to the front of the names -- I find it helps with organization.

Comment: Edited to respond to comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly `Drag & Drop` a folder onto the Xcode project and then select `Create Folder references for any added...`. I don't think you can directly create folders through Xcode. You can however add a `Build Phase` for copying files which will allow you to create folders in your bundle.

Comment: I guess that's the only way to handle it (and that requires including the folder whenever referring to the file in the code). In my case, I wound up just renaming one of the files to simplify things.